# Script SQL Login and User Mappings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, scripting

I need to script a specific SQL Login, with it's associated User Mappings and role memberships. Is this possible? If so, someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Why please? You'd normally do one or the other eg http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133

Comment: This is currently in a UAT environment. Going live on Friday, so need to create a script for the SQL DBA's to run, that takes care of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Script the logon in SSMS
- Script the user in SSMS
- Script the role in SSMS
- Do the sp_addrolemember manually

It's just as quick

Or modify this. Which is just as quick as using SSMS...

```
USE master
GO
CREATE LOGIN SomeLogin --FROM WINDOWS?
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO SomeLogin
GO
USE MYDB
GO
CREATE USER SomeUser FOR LOGIN SomeLogin
GRANT CONNECT TO SomeUser 
GO
CREATE ROLE SomeRole AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'SomeRole', 'SomeUser'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

OR... Use the **Azure User Management console - AUMC** to manage the Logins and Users.

It's a open source project available on codeplex [AUMC.codeplex.com](http://AUMC.codeplex.com)

> **Project Description**
>
> Azure User Management Console - AUMC is a User
>   Graphic Interface (GUI) that manages the users and logins of an Azure
>   SQL database.  The tool is simply converting your action into T-SQL
>   commands and execute them on the Azure SQL Database.

A quick simple tool with a user interface! Don

Enjoy!